# Find unicode by its code via grep

Tags: grep, regex, unicode, utf-8

How find a symbol by code of Unicode?

E.g. try find a space ('\u20' or '\u0020') in the second line:

`echo -e "u20\n \nfoo" |grep "\u20"` - found the literal `u20`, not the space line.

`echo -e "x20\n \nfoo" |grep -P "\x20"` - work. But don't fit for me, because `-P` don't work with '\u'.

Comment: Does it work for you substituting `u20` for space? `echo -e "u20\n \nfoo" | sed 's/u20/ /' | grep -m 1 " "`

Comment: Substitution don't fit, because need to find mass any symbols non-Ascii by their code.

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer (yes, you can answer your own question).

Comment: This is really difficult to test since you picked a whitespace character. It would be a lot easier to try `A` U+41 for example.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Dash and not Bash? I got totally different results for all of your code. Although Dash doesn't support Unicode, so why are you not using Bash or another language in the first place?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, was error in header. google.translator... thanks

Comment: Added a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this workaround solving your problem?
In bash:

```
$ export myvar='\u20'
$ echo $myvar
\u20
$ echo -e "u20\n \nfoo" | grep -P `sed 's/\\u/\\x/' <<<$myvar`

$ echo $myvar
\u20
```

The sed instruction substitutes the \u with \x of $myvar without changing the value of the environment variable itself.

Comment: I found a solve and updated question. It would be interesting to know which is faster: using `printf` or such replacements via `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

A solve: `grep "$(printf %b '\u20')"`

Like: `echo -e "u20\n \nfoo" | grep "$(printf %b '\u20')"`